# How to make some of links and paragraphs changeable via Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating custom theme. In that theme there are few specific items. In header there is email@email.com  `span`,   and  'Phone: xxx/xxxxxxx' `span`. Also there are few links to social media pages such as facebook, twitter, etc. How do I make these links point to custom destination and how do I give user an option to customize email and number phone that would be shown in paragraphs mentioned above. I want user to customize that data within Wordpress panel. It looks something like this:

header.php data that I want to make customizable:

```
<div id="social">
    <span>Tel: 385 312 3214</span>
    <span>Email: email@email.com</span>
</div>
```

And the footer.php data I want to make customizable (href="" part only):

```
<footer>
    <a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook-outline"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="ion-social-googleplus-outline"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="ion-social-linkedin-outline"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter-outline"></i></a>
    <p>email@email.com</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: you have to give the user a way so he can stroe these data in database and later you can fetch the data from the database and show it in header and footer

Comment: Yeah I could do that if I was building my own CMS or similar PHP application which in this case I don't. I understand what you are suggesting and I'd really like to do that, but I can't. I need it to happen within Wordpress itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to customized the data from wordpress dashboard.Then you need to create custom widgets for this. you can create easily by following code. Please put this code in function.php file in theme folder.

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Top Email Widget Area', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'id'            => 'email_text',
        'description'   => __( 'Email appear on header area.', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="label">',
        'after_title'   => '</div>',
    ) ); 
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Social Widget Area', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'id'            => 'social',
        'description'   => __( 'social appear on footer area.', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => '',
    ) );
```

After this when you run this script. you can see, which is display inside **Appearance->widgets** section.

After that please write this script, where you want to display.

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'email_text' ); ?>
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'social' ); ?>
```